# Workspace grid view in Elementary OS

Tags: workspace

I would love to have a 3x3 grid view of my workspaces on Elementary OS Loki. I've found an gnome extension on [this page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/) but following the install instructions doesn't give me "shell extensions" so i didn't know how to proceed... I couldn't find anymore help online, hence my question here, hope you can help me finding a solution for workspaces in gridview :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use this gnome extension because you are using elementary OS (`pantheon`, `gala`) and not `gnome-shell`.

I am pretty sure that you cannot do this under elementary OS, because this functionality is not implemented (and it uses only a single row of workspaces).